# Cubic convergence of Rayleigh quotient iteration?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Trefethen and Bau, Numerical Linear Algebra, p. 208 states that Rayleigh quotient iteration (combining Rayleigh quotient estimate for eigenvalues and inverse power iteration) converges cubically

> ...the convergence is ultimately cubic in the sense that if
>   $\lambda_J$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v^{(0)}$ is sufficiently
>   close to the eigenvector $q_J$, 
>   then $$\|v^{(k+1)} - (\pm q_J)\| =  O(\|v^{(k)} - (\pm q_J)\|^3)$$ and $$|\lambda^{(k+1)} - \lambda_J| =
> > O(|\lambda^{(k)} - \lambda_J|^3)$$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Their argument is as follows. Suppose that convergence occurs, and that
$\|v^{(k)} - q_J\| \leq \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$.
Then the Rayleigh quotient estimation for an eigenvalue gives an eigenvalue
estimate $\lambda^{(k)}$ with $|\lambda^{(k)} - \lambda_J| = O(\epsilon^2)$.

Then apply the proof of the inverse power iteration for one step to obtain $v^{(k+1)}$ from $v^{(k)}$ and $\lambda^{(k)}$, so that
$$\|v^{(k+1)} - q_J \|= O(|\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_J| \|v^{(k)} - q_J\|) = O(\epsilon^3)$$
with the constants in the big-Oh symbols uniform in sufficiently small neighborhoods.

I don't see the left most equality above, nor why the constants are uniform.

It seems that all power iteration gives is
$$O(|\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_J|/|\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_K|)$$
where $\lambda_K$ is the second closest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a high level explanation brushing some analysis under the rug.  Let's rewrite Theorem 27.2 as
$$
\|v^{(k+1)}-(\pm q_J)\| = O\left( \left|\frac{\mu-\lambda_J}{\mu-\lambda_K} \right|^{k+1} \right) = O\left( \left|\frac{\mu-\lambda_J}{\mu-\lambda_K} \right|^{k} \left|\frac{\mu-\lambda_J}{\mu-\lambda_K} \right| \right) = O\left(\|v^{(k)}-(\pm q_J)\| \ \left|\frac{\mu-\lambda_J}{\mu-\lambda_K} \right| \right)$$

For the Rayleigh quotient iteration, the $ \mu $ in the expression above is replaced with $ \lambda^{(k)} $.  The key to understanding the rest of the argument is that for $ j \neq J $, $ |\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_j|$ is approximately constant for $ v^{(k)} $ near $ q_J $.  This follows because the eigenvectors are stationary points of the Rayleigh quotient.  In particular, $|\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_K|$ is approximately a constant and can be absorbed into the $O$.

Combining these observations gives the result:
$$
\|v^{(k+1)}-(\pm q_J)\| = O(\|v^{(k)}-(\pm q_J)\| |\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_J|)$$

A formal proof of the cubic convergence of the Rayleigh quotient iteration can be found in *Applied Numerical Linear Algebra* by Demmel.